# Placing delimiter before a number in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file like this and I need to place a delimiter: `|` before  each number in the file.

Input:

```
sg_fxops_mm hello  2324
sg_fxops_cf  340
G_buc_call  4234
SG_buc_commloan  53465
SG_buc_call_chg  1
```

Expected output:

```
sg_fxops_mm hello | 2324
sg_fxops_cf | 340
G_buc_call | 4234
SG_buc_commloan | 53465
SG_buc_call_chg | 1
```

Comment: With your example data: `sed 's/  / | /' file`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture the first digit, replace it with `|`  and the captured digit:

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\)/| \1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

with GNU `awk` setting FS (not only a blank) and OFS ( `|` between spaces) you can get it.

```
awk -v FS='[[:blank:]]{2,}' '{print $1, $2}' OFS=" | " file

sg_fxops_mm hello | 2324
sg_fxops_cf | 340
G_buc_call | 4234
SG_buc_commloan | 53465
SG_buc_call_chg | 1
```